# Seperating a list of DataFrames named with the values of different list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list of 33 stock tickers that I used to pull tables off of of reuters summary pages.  I used a for loop to accomplish this and now I am left with a list of a list of DataFrames.  Here is the code:

```
company_data = []
for i in url_list:
    data = pd.read_html(io=i, flavor = None, header=0, index_col=0)
    company_data.append(data)
```

Pandas did a great job pulling the different tables from each page but now I am stuck with a giant list or a list of the different tables as DataFrames.  I would like to break up the list company_data and assign each list of DataFrames to the ticker symbol.  I made a dictionary:

```
c_dict = {t: d for t, d in zip(tickers, company_data)}
```

But, I'm stuck on how I can separate each key and item into it's own list of DataFrames with the key as the variable name.  For example, one of the tickers is 'SPG'.  I would like SPG to equal list of the DataFrames for SPG's stock data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Comment: Can you provide a single item from your url_list, so people can try to run your code to see what list is returned by pd.read_html?

Comment: My desired output would be outputting certain data into excel by ticker.  Here's an example url: 'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/SPG'.  Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: I figured it out!  I can just pull each individual piece of data I want, and zip it with the ticker list to match to the company.  Thanks guys!